# I want to change a string from user define special character using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the string `colormanagemnet` from user define special character like this:

**c!o@l#o$r$m%a^n&a*g?e(m)e@n!t**

using JavaScript or jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sc = "!@#$%^&*()?"
var txt = "colormanagemnet";

// dont know how to concat like this 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one handles uneven lengths and pads if necessary

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/AGv7w/)

```
var sc = "!@#$%^&*()?"
var txt = "colormanagemnet";
var newstr ="";
```

Most elegant is to use charAt with Tiago's remainder method:

```
for (var i=0,n=txt.length; i< n; i++) {
  newstr += txt.charAt(i)+sc.charAt(i % sc.length);
}
```

---

Here is one with padding, testing the longest string:

```
for (var i=0,n=Math.max(txt.length,sc.length); i< n; i++) {
  var char1 = txt.length>i?txt.charAt(i):"-"; // remove - if no padding
  var char2 = sc.length>i?sc.charAt(i):"~";  // remove ~ if no padding
  newstr += char1+char2;
}
alert(newstr);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can split each variables

```
sc.split("")

=> ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "?"]

txt.split("")

=>["c", "o", "l", "o", "r", "m", "a", "n", "a", "g", "e", "m", "n", "e", "t"]
```

And now you can run each character of `txt` and concatenate with each character of `sc`. If you have a different number of elements you can do something like this:

```
for(...){
   final = final + char_from_txt[i] + char_from_sc[i % sc_length];
}
```

Comment: of course, I can use charAt and something like that. but I think it is more easy to explain because it is visual :)

Comment: Hmm, I like the 
`i % sc.length`

Comment: in this case I imagine put the length in a external variable but in javascript I think there is no difference (in java it will).